# Pipeline using redisson

Tags: java, pipeline, redisson

I want to implement pipeline using redisson in my application.For that i have imported redisson 3.2.2 jar . And i have tried the following code below.

```
RBatch batch = redisson.createBatch();
RMap<Integer, Integer> map = batch.getMap("map");
Future<?> future1 = map.fastPutAsync(1, 2);
Future<?> future2 = map.putAsync(2, 3);
Future<?> future3 = map.fastPutAsync(3, 4);
List<?> futures = batch.execute();
```

But there is no method for .createBatch() in redisson jar .What could be the possible solution .Should i try another redisson version or is there any other method in which i can implement pipeline using redisson ?

Comment: were you able to find an alternative?